# try except block not working in my guessing game python

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
    num_of_guess = 0
    max_guess = 9
    hidden_num = 13
    while num_of_guess < max_guess:
        guess = int(input("Guess: "))
        try: 
            num_of_guess += 1
            if guess < hidden_num:
                print("Too low!")
            elif guess > hidden_num:
                print("too high!")
            elif guess == hidden_num:
                print("You win!")
                break
            else:
                print("You lose!")
                break
        except Exception as e:
            e = "Please enter a number!"
            continue
```

The error except message doesnt work and now when i guess the correct number it says you win but the game loop doesnt break.
The error when I enter a string :

```
Guess: ad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\XRX\Desktop\Python\guessing game 2.py", line 6, in <module>
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ad'
```

Comment: I want it to break the loop when I guess the correct number and to also show a custom error when a user enters a string instead of a number.

Comment: Your call to `input` is outside of the `try/except` block, so the error won't be caught.

Comment: Also, it's usually best practice to be specific in the errors you want to catch, so things like `Ctrl`+`C` to end a program still work. And if you want to print a custom error message, you don't have to reassign `e`. Just use `print` and print your error message to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the try-except block is only going to monitor the area indented within.  This error happens one line above the try-except (when you try to change the string to an int()).  Instead it's good practice to wrap the try-except block around a single statement so you can find a specific bug.

```
try:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
except ValueError as e:
    raise ValueError(f"bad value: {guess}")
```

Comment: can u pls send me the improved  version of my code?

Comment: I will for an upvote.

Comment: Can u answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307591/opencv-face-detection-problems) question?